# Storing Objective C custom model instance into swift class to id instance

Tags: objective-c, swift, typechecking, custom-data-type

I am using `swift 4.0` and `Objective C` into my existing project.
I have a Objective C custom model class `DetailsModel` and it has a property like

```
@interface DetailsModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) id model;
```

And I am using the instance of `DetailsModel` into my `swift` class and storing another Objective C custom model class instance to above property, like

```
let model = DetailsModel()
model.model = item
```

This instance `item` if from another Objective C custom class `CarModel`

Now the problem is when I check type of above stored item

```
if type(of: current.model) == type(of: CarModel())
```

This fails and console just prints like `Optional<Any>`

So I cant identify the object type and perform necessary actions, I checked everything else is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please change

```
if current.model is CarModel
```